# Difference between backbone.js and asp MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I am starting out a new project and I was wondering what would be the best stack to use. I have little experience with both backbone and asp MVC.

With performance and user experience in mind, would I be better creating a backbone project and get my data via ajax calls and the use templateing to render or am I better of using asp MVC.

What are the major differences between these both and what should decide which one to use.

Comment: backbone Is 180 degree different thing from asp.net MVC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you are comparing bananas with apples (they are very different) - but if you have decided to go down the Microsoft route you can make a new project that can use both MVC to serve web pages and the Web API to serve data / resource requests. That way you can use whatever technology best serves the need of the task you are on.

I am currently doing exactly this.
Some pages (like the .NET membership stuff) are provided as web pages via ASP.NET and MVC.
Some pages are just static html and use KnockoutJs (which is like Backbone but easier) with AJAX requests for JSON data from the Web API.

[Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training) offer courses on backbone, ASP.NET MVC and KnockoutJs - which might be a fast way for you to get started? There are many free courses too.

Comment: thanks man, this is the way i'm gonna go. Just realized about web api and asp mvc.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is a server side Technology for developing businesses web application via MVC pattern, whereas backbone is a client side library for implementing MVVM design pattern which is independent from any server side programming Technologies like `ASP.NET , PHP , JSP` ,...
but you can join this two technologies to design a responsive business web application.